# can /etc/skel directory's files and directories automatically copied over to a existing user’s like with the newly created ones?

Tags: ssh, aws

The /etc/skel directory contains files and directories that are automatically copied over to a new user’s when it is created from useradd command.
But , when checked with the old existing users , it do not contains all the files and directories (.ssh directory in my case) as it should have inside /etc/skel.

1. I have uncommented  SKEL=/etc/skel in  /etc/default/useradd.
2. placed .ssh directory inside /etc/skel
   But the .ssh directory is not showing when logged in from existing users , where it works fine with the newly created users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to copy over the files yourself, remembering:

- not to overwrite existing *customised* versions (but possibly overwriting unchanged originals)
- to fix up ownership (and permissions)
- to skip users whose home directory doesn't exist

You would need to determine the set of users to process (`getent passwd` or the file `/etc/passwd`). On some systems it might be every user in the `users` group. On others it might be every account with a UID ≥ 1000. And so on. Or you might prefer to iterate across all the directories under `/home` regardless of entries in the user database.

Comment: Thank a lot. That was useful.